# UIView animation block not animation view's subviews

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I am unable to achieve any animation with the following code:

```
if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    [UIView transitionFromView:tableView
                        toView:mapView
                      duration:1.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                    completion:nil
         ];
    }
if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
    [UIView transitionFromView:mapView
                        toView:tableView
                      duration:1.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
                    completion:nil
         ];
}
```

The views are actually swapping, but just without any animation. It's quite strange. I have also tried to swap `mapView` and `tableView` with `self.view.subviews` like so (`objectAtIndex:0` is a `toolBar`):

```
if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    [UIView transitionFromView:[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1]
                        toView:[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:2]
                      duration:1.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                    completion:nil
         ];
    }
if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
    [UIView transitionFromView:[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:2]
                        toView:[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1]
                      duration:1.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
                    completion:nil
         ];
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are using the wrong options. With this method, you should use [the constants `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft` and `…Right`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAnimationOptions) instead.

The old constants `UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft` and `…Right` should only be used for the non-block-based method `+setAnimationTransition:…`. These constants have values 1 and 2 respectively, while the ones I mentioned above have values 1 << 20 and 2 << 20, which are totally different.

Comment: Thanks very much! I guess it's a bug in Xcode that it doesn't suggest or even recognizes this option when compiling (although it compiles without errors, just doesn't change the text colour to a "OK" compiled option).

Comment: @Canada: It's not a bug in Xcode, but that the C standard (`gcc`) don't prevent constants of different `enum`s from mixing up.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I looked at the class a bit more and just saw the compiler stuff. Thanks :)

Comment: @Canada The reason why you don't get a compiler warning is because it is an enumeration, which when you boil it down to its essence, is just an integer.  This means that passing in the value without 'Option' in it was perfectly valid, since its value was an integer as well.

Comment: Was totally stuck on this one, thanks for the good eyeballs :D

Comment: Sir, you rock. I got stuck on that thing for hours! Very slight difference but everything works now. Thank you so much! :D

Comment: I wish i could give it more than just +1!